# Green's theorem and conversion to polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates, greens-theorem

While subject to the force:

$$F(x,y) = y^3i + (x^3 + 3xy^2)j$$
a particle travels counterclockwise once around circle of radius 3. Find work done using Green's theorem.

So $P = y^3$, $Q=x^3+3xy^2$, and $dP/dy =3y^2$ and $dQ/dx = 3x^2 + 3y^2$

So where do I go from here? Why do I have to convert to polar coordinates from here? How do I do this?

Comment: The formula for work is $\int_C \vec{F} d\vec{r}$ where $F$ is the force, $C$ is the curve that describes the trajectory of the object. You need to calculate this. How you do that might be related to Green's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

By Green's theorem
$$\int_{C}\vec F\cdot \,d\vec r=\int\int_{A}\bigg(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\biggr)\,dA$$
where $A$ is the area that the circle of radius $3$ encloses. I.e. $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}\,:\, x^2+y^2\leq 9\}$. Substituting $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x},\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ the second integrals equals to
$$\iint_{\{(x,y):\,x^2+y^2\leq 9\}}3 x^2\,dx\,dy $$

Now the easiest way to solve this is to use polar coordinates. Set $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$. In polar coordinates the integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{3}3\cdot r^3\cdot \cos ^2\theta\,dr\,d\theta&=\frac{81}{4}\cdot \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2\theta\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{81}{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos 2\theta+1}{2}\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{81\pi}{4}+\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos 2\theta}{2}\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{81\pi}{4}+\frac{\sin 2\theta}{4}\biggl|_{0}^{2\pi}\\
&=\frac{81\pi}{4}
\end{align}
where in the second equality we used the inequality $\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta-1$.

Comment: Wait are your calculations for dq/dx and dp/dy right? @dem0nakos

Comment: @Jwan622 You also did the same calculation. You found $\partial Q/\partial x=3x^2+3y^2$ and $\partial P/ \partial y=3y^2$. So $\partial Q/\partial x-\partial P/ \partial y=3x^2$.

Comment: ohhhhh, god I'm sorry

Comment: @Jwan622 its ok !